# I want to redirect to another page which consist only the details of the individual object on which the user clicks. Someone help me how can i do this

Tags: reactjs

I want to redirect to another page which consist only the details of the individual object on which the user clicks. Someone help me how can i do this. Thanks in advance.

```
function Dashboard() {
    const [token, setToken] = useContext(store)
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
      axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/events').then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setEvents(res.data)
      }).catch(err => {console.log(err)})
    }, [])
    
    if(!token){
        return (
            <Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />
          ) 
    }
  //using map function to show data in a list. Here i want to access single item when i click on it//
    return (
    <>
    <div className='eventelement'>
      <ul>
        {
        events.map(event => (     
          <section className=''>
          <li key={event._id}>
          <table className='eventtable' border={1}>
          <th className='eventth'><div className='eventtitle'> {event.eventname} </div></th>
          <tr><div className='eventhoster'> hosted by: {event._id} </div></tr>
          <tr><div className='eventdetails'> <label className='eventsh'>Event type: </label>{event.eventtype} </div></tr>
          
          </table>
          </li><br />
          </section>             
        ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        
    </div>
    </>
  )
  }

export default Dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each element a click event handler that redirects the user to, say, `/events/${event._id}`. If you're using a recent version of `react-router-dom`, its `useNavigate` hook should give you a callback to navigate to another page.

Then add a `<Route path="/events/:id" element={<EventDetailPage/>} />` to your routes.

Comment: Thats cool but how do i get the data of that particular element on the new page

Comment: @Venkat use the `id` path parameter to query it from the same source you'd get the full list of events from. The router package exports `useParams`, a hook that returns all params as a record